# How to run a pipeline under a specific branch in Azure Data Factory using the Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

Using the [Azure Python SDK for Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.datafactorymanagementclient?view=azure-python), how can I trigger a pipeline run that only exists inside a branch? For example: I may have a pipeline "X" that is inside branch "dev" but not in branch "main".

Comment: Have you tried any approach? Please share the error and blockage if you faced during implementation.

Comment: Yes, I have been using the SDK DataFactoryManagementClient class, as linked in my question. I can easily trigger and create pipeline runs using it, but nowhere in it I find any argument or parameter to specify branches in the ADF, so I don't even know where to start here.

Comment: @eduardokapp, did you figure out any solution to this problem. I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, not yet. Can't seem to find explicit info on this in microsoft docs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to programmatically run ADF pipeline from a specific branch. When you trigger the pipeline programmatically, it will try to run the pipeline version which are already published to the ADF Service. Any newly created ADF pipeline or artifacts source control development branches has to debugged/tested from ADF studio manually. Unless those changes are published to ADF service, they cannot be triggered programmatically.